# Is this a problem with Array push() in Svelte or is it something I'm doing wrong?

Tags: arrays, promise, push, svelte

I've been wracking my brain over this issue for several hours now, and although I've found a workaround to the problem, I can't get over the fact that it's happening at all. I don't understand it. There seems to be some sort of an issue in using Array.push() within a promise handler. I've created the below test code to demonstrate it, and it's reproducable in Svelte REPL. Am I just doing something wrong?

```
<script>
  const myPromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      resolve('foo');
    }, 300);
  });

  let itemsA = [];
  let itemsB = [];

  const addItem = (item) => {
    itemsA[itemsA.length] = item;
    itemsB.push(item);
  }
    
  const loadItems = (last) => {
    addItem("Begin");

    myPromise
      .then((value) => {
        addItem(value);
      });

    addItem("End");
    return true;
  };

  loadItems();
</script>

<div>Items A: {itemsA}</div>
<div>Items B: {itemsB}</div>
```

I would think that itemsB.push(item) should do the same thing as itemsA[itemsA.length] = item, and it does, except when called from inside the promise handler.

I get the following results instead:

```
Items A: Begin,End,foo
Items B: Begin,End
```

Edit: I've eliminated promises as the source of the weirdness. The following code illustrates it more simply.

```
<script>
  let itemsA = [];
  let itemsB = [];

  const addItem = (item) => {
    itemsA[itemsA.length] = item;
    itemsB.push(item);
  }

    const clickHandler = () => {
        addItem('click');
    }
    
    addItem('load');
</script>

<div>Items A: {itemsA}</div>
<div>Items B: {itemsB}</div>
<button on:click={clickHandler}>Click Me</button>
```

Comment: This is the way promises work.  The `addItem` in the outer scope of `loadItems` runs before the `addItem` inside the promise handler.

For more information, there's a great video here:  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8aGhZQkoFbQ&ab_channel=JSConf

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Actually that has nothing to do with the promise. When you add a button and log the arrays, you see that 'foo' is in 'itemsB' as well, it's just not rendered.
From the Svelte Docs

> Because Svelte's reactivity is based on assignments, using array methods like .push() and .splice() won't automatically trigger updates. A subsequent assignment is required to trigger the update.
> The according [tutorial](https://svelte.dev/tutorial/updating-arrays-and-objects)

You can use .push() if it's followed by a reassignment of the array to itself

```js
itemsB.push(item);
itemsB = itemsB
```

or alternatively use the spread operator syntax

```js
itemsB = [...itemsB, item]
```

Here's a [REPL](https://svelte.dev/repl/ad6e5d5ffee64ef5937723adfa49245f?version=3.44.1) to try this out

Comment: This is useful, and I'll be sure not to use push (I kind of narrowed it down myself as you can see from the edit I added just as you were adding this response).. I'm not sure I understand why Svelte doesn't render it though. Shouldn't it?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean..? You mean why it's not rendered with just using .push()?

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean.

Comment: Well, I think I'll have to pass this question to the makers of Svelte... :-) I just accepted (for now) that the assignment is important for everything to behave as expected

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
https://svelte.dev/repl/0dedb37665014ba99e05415a6107bc21?version=3.53.1

use a library called `svelox`.
It allows you to use the `Array` native api(push/splice...etc.) without reassignment statements.